# ImageMagick: Cylinder keeping original on background

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to make a cylinder wrap via ImageMagick. It's working fine on creating the cylinder, but it's keeping the original image on back.

```
magick \
-verbose \
\( \
      -size 2585x1181 \
      xc:blue \
      \( \
         ./images/test.png \
         -geometry +820+0 \
      \) \
      -composite \
      -geometry 730x390 \
      -roll -230+0 \
      -crop 270x408+0+0 \
      +append \
\) \
-gravity south -background Transparent -splice 0x40 \
\( +clone -sparse-color barycentric '0,0 black 273,0 white' \) \
\( -clone 1 -function arcsin 0.5 \) \
\( -clone 1 -level 0%,100% \
            -function polynomial -4,4,0 -gamma 2 \
            +level 50%,0%  \) \
-delete 1 \
-virtual-pixel Transparent \
-define compose:args=0x40 \
-compose Displace \
-composite \
./output/out.png
```

[image]

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Make a mask for the back area.

Comment: This is not a bug. It is just the way the math works when doing the distorting in Imagemagick.

Comment: Pad you image in width on both the left and right sides so that the width is twice what you have so that the pad shows in the back of the cylinder rather than the image.

Comment: Post your input image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in Imagemagick 7, whether a bug or a design feature, the distortion needs to be composed as one image with the X and Y distortions in the first two channels rather than as separate images.

In Imagemagick 6, this works

```
convert \
-verbose \
\( \
      -size 2585x1181 \
      xc:blue \
      \( \
         test.png \
         -geometry +820+0 \
      \) \
      -composite \
      -resize 730x390 \
      -roll -230+0 \
      -crop 270x408+0+0 +repage \
\) \
-gravity south -background none -splice 0x40 \
\( -clone 0 -set colorspace Gray -alpha off -sparse-color barycentric '0,0 black 270,0 white' \) \
\( -clone 1 -function arcsin 0.5 \) \
\( -clone 1 \
            -function polynomial -4,4,0 -gamma 2 \
            +level 50%,0% \) \
-delete 1 \
-background none -virtual-pixel none \
-define compose:args=20x40 \
-compose Displace \
-composite \
test_out1.png
```

[image]

But in Imagemagick 7, you have to do

```
magick \
\( \
      -size 2585x1181 \
      xc:blue \
      \( \
         test.png \
         -geometry +820+0 \
      \) \
      -composite \
      -geometry 730x390 \
      -roll -230+0 \
      -crop 270x408+0+0 \
\) \
-gravity south -background Transparent -splice 0x40 \
\( +clone \
   -set colorspace Gray \
   -alpha off \
   -sparse-color barycentric '0,0 black 273,0 white' \
  \( -clone 0 -function arcsin 0.5 \) \
  \( -clone 0 \
     -function polynomial -4,4,0 -gamma 2 \
     +level 50%,0%  \) \
  \( +clone \) \
  -delete 0 \
  -combine \
  -alpha off \
\) \
-virtual-pixel Transparent \
-define compose:args=20x40 \
-compose Displace \
-composite \
+channel \
test_out3.png
```

[image]